# Webresource.axd doesn't load on my asp.net application running on my web farm

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, web-controls, webresource.axd

I'm working on an ASP.net web application.  I'm getting errors on some of my pages where I get runtime JavaScript errors.

I've narrowed the problem down to a single ASP Menu control on the master page.  I created a blank page with just the ASP Menu control.  The ASP Menu control is bound to `Web.sitemap`.  The page intermittently gives runtime errors.

However, if I refresh the page, the error may or may not appear on any given page load.  Sometimes, it works; sometimes, the browser throws runtime errors when loading the page or when I mouse over the ASP Menu control.

When I catch the error in Visual Studio, the message is "microsoft jscript runtime error 'sys' is undefined".  When I Google for this message, I find that it is usually associated with AJAX.  However, the ONLY thing on the page is a single ASP control.

There is absolutely no Javascript on the page except for what gets generated by the .net framework.

What could be causing this problem?

**UPDATE** I've found out that my environment actually has load balancing with a web farm of three servers servicing the URL.  When I access the application on any one of the servers individually by IP address, everything works fine.

To clarify, I understand that when a user hits the public-facing URL, it resolves to x.x.x.1. x.x.x.1 is the address for a switch which routes the request to either x.x.x.2, x.x.x.3, or x.x.x.4.

**When I use the public-facing URL, I find that some of the axd file requests are intermittently rerouted to Error.aspx!  WTF!?!?!?!?!?**

I'm told that this is the result of a security feature that is meant to protect me from cross-site scripting and other assorted bad stuff.  What can I do?

**Update** After taking out some error page auto-redirects, I get a more meaningful error message: `ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.`

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure all the servers have the same asp.net version. Something that could affect it, is partially applying the recent Microsoft patch for the padding oracle vulnerability (to some servers, instead of All)
- Make sure all the servers [use the same machine key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx#paght000007_webfarmdeploymentconsiderations). When doing so either use [protected sections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtkwfdky.aspx) or configure it at the machine level web.config / learn from the [recent vulnerability to protect sensitive information in the web.config](http://eglasius.blogspot.com/2010/09/aspnet-padding-oracle-impact-on-aspnet.html).

Comment: What is this "machine key" you refer to?  Where do I check it?

Comment: @Rice see links in the edit. Asp.net uses the machine key to encrypt the parameters of webresource.axd, if you don't explicitly configure it in the application web.config it auto generates a new one for your application (on each appdomain restart).